# How do I get the values of x-axis(FPR) and y-axis(TPR) in ROC curve

Tags: r, plot, plotly, roc

I'm trying to make a ROC curve using `plotly.js` with the values obtained in R.

In `plotly`, I have to fill out the values(x-axis, y-axis) to make a plot.

But, I don't know how to get the values when I use Logistic Regression function `glm` or `multinom`(in `nnet` packages).

```
df <- data.frame(age = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50),height = c(150, 161, 141, 155, 180), house = c("0", "0", "0", "1", "1"))
smp_size <- floor(nrow(df) * (0.6))
train_idx <- sample(seq_len(nrow(df)), size = smp_size)

train <- df[train_idx, ]
validation <- df[-train_idx, ]

validation_x <- validation[c("age", "height")]
validation_y <- validation[["house"]]

m <- glm(house ~ age + height, data = train, family = 'binomial')
y_pred <- predict(m, validation_x)

library(plotROC)
plotROC(validation_y, y_pred)
```

[image]

I want to know how to get the values of x-axis(FPR) and y-axis(TPR) in ROC curve

thank you.

Comment: oh! I didn't know this function. Thank you for your helpful answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the function `roc()` in package `pROC`:

```
# install.packages("pROC")
library(pROC)
my.roc <- roc(validation_y, y_pred)
```

`roc()` returns a list recording specificities(x-axis), sensitivities(y-axis), thresholds, AUC, and other information. You can use `$` to extract them:

```
my.roc$specificities
my.roc$sensitivities
```